# jquery lightbox gallery with thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, lightbox, image-gallery

I need a lightbox light [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) that will popup a lightbox but have a gallary format like [this](http://themeforest.s3.amazonaws.com/86_jquery/gallery.html#i/photos/thatch.jpg) or [galleria](http://file:///Users/mattelhotiby/Downloads/galleria%202/themes/classic/classic-demo.html)...basically a lighbox with thumbnails of the images...i cant seem to find one out there..any suggestions

Comment: Look at this gallery, that i wrote few days ago. It very similar to what google use: https://github.com/creotiv/jquery-photowall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with prettyPhoto...it has exactly what i was looking for